# jpype.startjvm exits without giving any error message

Tags: java, python, jpype

I am trying to use [Python MPXJ](https://pypi.org/project/mpxj/) to analyze info from mpp file. In my Windows 10 machine, I have a 32bit Python 3.8.0 installed and `JPYPE` prepared by `pip install jpype1`. I am also installing JRE 32bit in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_301`.

However, The following script simply fails

```py
import jpype

print(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath())
jpype.startJVM()
print("JVM successfully started")
jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

It shows the default path as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_301\bin\client\jvm.dll`, However the next print line is not executed, nor do `startJVM` give any error output. The execution result is as the following

```sh
> python testjvm.py
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_301\bin\client\jvm.dll
```

So `startJVM` get executed, but exit without giving anything.

Is there a way to further debugging what might be the problem?

---

I am doing further debugging with `ipython` per John's suggestion. It goes to `c:\python38\lib\site-packages\jpype\_core.py(226)` with the following context

```py
> c:\python38\lib\site-packages\jpype\_core.py(225)startJVM()
    223                         % (','.join([str(i) for i in kwargs])))
    224
3-> 225     try:
    226         _jpype.startup(jvmpath, tuple(args),
    227                        ignoreUnrecognized, convertStrings, interrupt)

ipdb> jvmpath
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_301\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll'
ipdb> args
args = []
kwargs = {}
ipdb> tuple(args)
()
ipdb> ignoreUnrecognized
False
ipdb> convertStrings
False
ipdb> interrupt
False
```

Then no matter I press `s` or `n` on `_jpype.startup`, the ipython exit without any prompt

Comment: @JohnHennig, I use ipython to step into the `startJVM`. It goes to `lib\site-packages\jpype\_core.py(225)` then exit when executing `_jpype.startup`. I am adding detail information in the original post.

Is it necessary that a 32-bit Visual Studio is used to compile 32-bit jpype? Previous I am using the same Visual Studio to compile `youcompleteme` pyc for VIM 32bit, it works fine.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHennig, after further investigation, I find it is not possible to run python x86 with JPype in a x64 windows, even with a java x86 installed. I will detail it in an answer post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for John Hennig's comment, which point out the root cause may be x86 and x64 incompatibility issue.

I do some further debugging per [JVM startup debugging](https://github.com/jpype-project/jpype/tree/master/project/debug/windows). Basically it uses [Dumpbin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=msvc-160) utility which come togehter with Visual Studio to check every component to see if it is x86 or x64. If any of them is incompatible, the jvm start will crash.

Turn out the `python.exe` and `jvm.dll` in my machine are all x86. However, when using `where` to locate the dependencies

```
    KERNEL32.dll
    USER32.dll
    ADVAPI32.dll
    WSOCK32.dll
    WINMM.dll
    VERSION.dll
    PSAPI.DLL
    VCRUNTIME140.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
```

It turns out the first dll `KERNEL32.dll` is located in `c:\Windows\System32`, and it is x64. The same is for other dlls. Since they are system default dlls in x64 windows, it will be very tricky to replace them with x86 ones. So it is not possible to use python x86 version with JPype in x64 windows.

The solution is straight forward, changing python/java to x64 version fixes the issue.